# How to set a trigger for two buckets in AWS lamda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm very new to AWS Lambda and was reading about S3 Buckets and Triggers. I was curious how you would code your lambda function to wait for 2 separate buckets to be called. Like 'a' is put in bucket 1 and 'b' is put in bucket 2 and my lambda function will execute a+b.So only if 'a' has been added tot he bucket the Lambda function will return an error. How can you set the Lambda function to execute(without returning an error message) by making it wait for both buckets?